# Setting headers in requests.session() creates timeout issue (socket.timeout: The read operation timed out)

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, request-headers

I am working on python 3.7 and trying to scrape data from website,  below is my code

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
session.headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46'}
base_url="any_website"
res=session.get(base_url, timeout=25)
```

The above code causes: socket.timeout: The read operation timed out exception

However after removing headers, the same code. works.
can anyone help me with the issue.

Comment: What happens when you drop the `timeout=25`?

Comment: nothing works except removing user agent

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a 200 response when I copy paste your code. I tried e.g. `https://educk.io` as a test. What site did use for your request? May it be a sever side issue after all?
(Sorry for not putting this into a comment. Seems like I did not earn the reputation for commenting, yet).
Just to make sure: I'm also on `python3.7`

Answer (score 0):

strange but removing user-agent solved the issue.